# summary in header with grouping option

Tags: jqgrid

does anyone have idea how can I have summary on head of my grouping column, there are pivot option but all my project are oriented with grouping option, there is a summary on bottom but this is european notation I need american notation to have summary in head, in the same row where we have expend/collapsing icon, please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the loadComplete use this function (changing "yourGridId to the id you used to name your grid):

```
$("#yourGridId tr.jqfoot").each(function () {
    var summaryrow = $(this);
    var level = summaryrow.attr('jqfootlevel');
    var groupSelector = 'tr.jqgroup.' + "yourGridId" + 'ghead_' + level + ':first';
    var grouprow = summaryrow.prevAll(groupSelector); 
    grouprow.children('td').attr('colSpan', 1); 
    var childrenSkipFirst = summaryrow.children(':nth-child(n+' + (2) + ')');        
    summaryrow.children().remove(); 
    grouprow.append(childrenSkipFirst);
})
```

This puts the summary row's cells values in the collapsed row. Notice you could have to change the number 2 in *var childrenSkipFirst = summaryrow.children(':nth-child(n+' + (2) + ')');* to another onw if you see the summary cells in collapsed row are not in line with the column header.